# Is ist possible to use boost 1.43 with Visual Studio 2012 (vc11)

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2012

I still need to support old software that was compiled with Visual Studio 2008 (VC9) and Boost 1.43 using the Boost Serialization to read a binary archive.

However the software I'm using to write the binary archive is now compiled with Visual Studio 2012 (VC11) and Boost 1.54, producing archives that cannot be read by the old software.

Is it somehow possible to use Boost 1.43 together with VC11?
I already checked http://boost.teeks99.com, but there only boost binaries for VC10 are available.
I also downloaded the Boost 1.43 source code and tried to compile it with VC11 myself.
However, VC11 is not supported by Boost 1.43 I get allot of warnings.

My question:
- has anyone used Boost 1.43 together with VC11 already?
- are there binaries available for download somewhere already?
- or, how can I compile Boost 1.43 with VC11?

Thanks in advance for any hints or suggestions.

Comment: It is possible to use Boost with MSVC11. Note that you're mixing several unrelated questions under a misleading title.

Comment: Pretty unlikely that your solving the right problem.  Binary serialization is a bad idea any day, but it is much more likely that the *data* has changed instead of boost.  C++11 saw to that.  Focus on the actual objects you serialize.  If they use any standard C++ library classes then you've got a problem you can't solve without a time machine.

Comment: @Igor R.: sorry forgot to add boost version to the title - added 1.43

Comment: @Hans Passant: I agree binary serialization is a bad idea but this decision cannot be changed anymore and I have to find a solution now. The data structure for sure has not changed (I have checked that) - however it might be that the VC11 representation of the structure might be different from VC9. The problem is that boost guarantees backward compatibility but no "forward compatibility", i.e. what is written with boost 1.43 can be read by boost 1.53 but the other way round is not guaranteed...